# NSURLConnection didReceiveData not loading data

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to get data from a website to display it inside a table view

My code:

```
-(void)loadTutorials {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://www.example.com/search?q=" stringByAppendingString:self.searchString]];
    NSURLRequest *UrlString = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:UrlString
                                                          delegate:self];

    [connection start];
    NSLog(@"Started");

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
        TFHpple *tutorialsParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:data];

        NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"//div[@id='header']/div[@class='window']/div[@class='item']/div[@class='title']/a";
        NSArray *tutorialsNodes = [tutorialsParser searchWithXPathQuery:tutorialsXpathQueryString];

        NSMutableArray *newTutorials = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (TFHppleElement *element in tutorialsNodes) {

            Data *tutorial = [[Data alloc] initWithTitle: [[element firstChild] content]
                                                     Url: [@"http://www.example.com" stringByAppendingString: [element objectForKey:@"href"]]
                              ];

            [newTutorials addObject:tutorial];


        }

        _objects = newTutorials;
        [self.tableView reloadData];


}
```

but the data is not showing up, is the data not finished loading?
I got it to working without NSURLConnection but then it will stop the program until the data is recieved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connectionDidFinishLoading:)

```
connection:didReceiveData:
```

is called in a incrementally manner.

> The newly available data. The delegate should concatenate the contents
>   of each data object delivered to build up the complete data for a URL
>   load.

So this means you should append new data within this method.

Then, in

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

you should manipulate your data.

So, for example

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    // Create space for containing incoming data
    // This method may be called more than once if you're getting a multi-part mime
    // message and will be called once there's enough date to create the response object
    // Hence do  a check if _responseData already there
    _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // Append the new data
    [_responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // Parse the stuff in your instance variable now    
}
```

Obviously you should also implement the delegate responsible for error handling.

A simple note is the following. If data is too big and you need to do some computations stuff (e.g. parsing), you could block the UI. So, you could move the parsing in a different thread (GCD is your friend). Then when finished you could reload the table in the main thread.

Take a look also here for further info: [NSURLConnectionDataDelegate order of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564435/nsurlconnectiondatadelegate-order-of-functions).